# Apply script to multiple sets of 2 dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm going to have 5 sets of select dropdowns with the same details in all 10 menus. They're going to be in pairs and if in any of the pairs you choose one of the options, the other select box has the option disabled.

I've got the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').change(function () {
        $('select.fix1 option').attr('disabled', false);
        $('select.fix1').each(function() {
            var val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
            if (!val) return;
            $('select.fix1 option').filter(function() {
                return $(this).val() == val;
            }).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    });
});
```

Which applies the rule perfectly to 2 dropdowns, but how can I apply it to the fix1, fix2, fix3, fix4 and fix5 pairings without repeating the code 5 times?

Comment: Post your HTML and explain bit more about the way you tried

Comment: The html is just 10 dropdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For jQuery selectors you can combine multiple selectors with comma ( like css-seletors ):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').change(function () {
        $('select.fix1 option, select.fix2 option, select.fix3 option').attr('disabled', false);
        $('select.fix1,select.fix2,select.fix3').each(function(key, el) {
            var val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
            if (!val) return;
            $(el).find('option').filter(function() {
                return $(this).val() == val;
            }).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    });
});
```

But it's better to have some commot class to right selector only once like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').change(function () {
        $('select.commonClass option').attr('disabled', false);
        $('select.commonClass').each(function(key, el) {
            var val = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
            if (!val) return;
            $(el).find('option').filter(function() {
                return $(this).val() == val;
            }).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: But what about the part after if (!val) return; where it says select.fix1 option again?

Comment: Yep. It's too. Sorry - i miss. See updated code ( we can duplicate selector there, but it's not good idea, so we'll use current element )